# Custom behavior with radio buttons and/or checkboxes. Accessibility ( WCAG 2.0 )

Tags: accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

I want to reveal some hidden text/elements(whatever) when some checkboxes/radio buttons are selected(assume there is a list of checkboxes/radio buttons to choose from).

What should I do to meet the WCAG 2.0 AA standards?

And how exactly radio buttons/checkboxes are understood by AT users, because obviously this isn't the supposed behavior of checkboxes/radio buttons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your last statement gives me pause: *"And how exactly radio buttons/checkboxes are understood by AT users, because obviously this isn't the supposed behavior of checkboxes/radio buttons."*

If you have non-standard behavior for your radios/checkboxes, will the sighted user be confused too?

With 'normal' behaving radios/checkboxes, the AT user will understand them just like a sighted person does - experience.  You learn that a radio is a group of mutually exclusive choices whereas a list of checkboxes allows multiple choices.  The screen reader will read the role of the object so the AT user will know what to do.

Now, if you're hiding/unhiding objects based on those selections, the AT user needs to be notified.  That's typically done with [aria-live](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-live).  By default, an aria-live region will be read if the text changes or an object is added to the DOM which should include being unhidden if you're doing it via display:none.  If you unhide by moving an offscreen object to onscreen, or changing the clipping rectangle, or changing the size of the object, aria-live will not help.

Also look at [aria-relevant](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-relevant).  By default, it's value is 'additions text', which is the behavior I mentioned above.  If you need the aria-live region to be read on other conditions, look at the other values of aria-relevant.